# Removing Specific Border Side from OutlineInputBorder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My goal is to display two textfield's above each other with a solid border around them. Unfortunately, I'm not able to specify that for the top textfield, there should be no bottom border. The following picture shows what the current status is. Between the two textfields, there is a thick border which is twice the size of the individual borders as the two textfields.

My question is now: is there a simple way to make this border between the two textfields the same size as the standard border by removing either the bottom border side from the first textfield or the top border side from the second textfield respectively?

[image]

The corresponding code looks as follows:

```html
body: Column(
children: <Widget>[
  Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Color(0xffff8f00),
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 3.0,
            //style: BorderStyle.none,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        hintText: "Email or username",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.white70,
        ),
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      ),
      controller: myEmailUsernameController,
    ),
  ),
  Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Color(0xffff8f00),
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        hintText: "Password",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.white70,
        ),
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      ),
      obscureText: showPW,
      controller: myPasswordController,
    ),
  ),
],
),
```

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do that if you have BorderRadius to any decoration. Instead you can try translating the bottom textfield to overlap the border for the top. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: To underline what @SudhanshuBhagwat said, you can basically both wrap the fields inside a Stack to overlap them and with positioning align them to  get the same outline sizing

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
Container(
        color: Color(0xffff8f00),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3)
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Email or username",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.white70,
                  ),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.white,
                thickness: 3,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  // enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  //   borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0),
                  //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  //     bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  //     bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  hintText: "Password",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.white70,
                  ),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```